# How to hide java script in browser page source?

Tags: javascript

i wanted to secure my javascript code from other. Please suggest me how to do that. i wanted this  code to me secure by hackers and developers. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide Javascript because the browser downloads and executes it because its design is to work as client-side. Maybe you can give a try to javascript [obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/) that will make it hard to read only.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the JS is very difficult. But u can minify the JS-File as an alternative. So it is very hard to understand the context. It changes the declaration to letters, so it is unreadable. Uglify is very nice. There are also some online Tools to do that.

Uglify JS: http://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

It is now being used by the jQuery project.